# Knockout Table : Highlight a Table Row

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, html-table, knockout-3.0

I have an Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnkUser/qWmat/320/) here. In this Table I wish to achieve Highlighting a Particular Row selected. If unselected Row should not be highlighted. 
One of many sample I found [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/6FCEe/) but I am unable to incorporate them inside my Example Fiddle Above.
Below is the HTML Code which shows basic Table.

```
<table id="devtable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr data-bind=" click: $parent.select  ">
        <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Status"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

ID :


Name :


Status :

### Here is the knockout function to do manipulations

```
<Script>
var rowModel = function (id, name, status) {
    this.ID = ko.observable(id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(name);
    this.Status = ko.observable(status);
};

var myData = [{
    id: "001",
    name: "Jhon",
    status: "Single"
}, {
    id: "002",
    name: "Mike",
    status: "Married"
}, {
    id: "003",
    name: "Marrie",
    status: "Complicated"
}];

function MyVM(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray(data.map(function (i) {
        return new rowModel(i.id, i.name, i.status);
    }));

    self.select = function(item) {
        self.selected(item);
        self.enableEdit(true);
    };


    self.flashCss = ko.computed(function () {
        //just an example

        return 'flash';
    });


    self.selected = ko.observable(self.items()[0]);

    self.enableEdit = ko.observable(false);

    self.changeTableData = function() {
// How do I change the Data here and it should also reflect on the Page.
// If I do binding depending on condition it gives me error
if(true){
var myData = [{
    id: "001",
    name: "Jhon",
    status: "Single"
}, {
    id: "002",
    name: "Mike",
    status: "Married"
}, {
    id: "003",
    name: "Marrie",
    status: "Complicated"
}];
}
else{
 myData = [{
    id: "111",
    name: "ABC",
    status: "Single"
}, {
    id: "222",
    name: "XYZ",
    status: "Married"
}, {
    id: "3333",
    name: "PQR",
    status: "Complicated"
}];
}
}   

}

ko.applyBindings(new MyVM(myData));
</script>
```

---

### CSS code below

```
.flash { background-color: yellow; }
```

Comment: Please add the code in your fiddle to your question (preferably in a runnable snippet). That way, your post will remain valuable if ever your fiddle breaks or gets removed.

Comment: Updated question with complete Code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `css` binding to add the `.flash` class based on the currently selected value:

```
<tr data-bind="click: $parent.select, 
               css: { flash: $parent.selected() === $data }">
  ...
</tr>
```

If you don't like this logic being defined in the view, you can pass a reference to the `selected` observable and create a computed property inside your `RowModel`:

```
var RowModel = function( /* ... */ selectedRow) {
  // ...
  this.isSelected = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return selectedRow() === this;
  }, this);
}
```

Here's the quick fix in your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wa78zoe4/

---

P.S. if you want toggle-behavior, update `select` to:

```
self.select = function(item) {
  if (item === self.selected()) {
    self.selected(null);
    self.enableEdit(false);
  } else {
    self.selected(item);
    self.enableEdit(true);
  }
};
```

Comment: If in case I could ask for Paging on the Same Table. Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnkUser/975ncawv/128/)
Rererence Fiddle I used was http://jsfiddle.net/LAbCv/

Comment: Just an update to let you know I tried Most part by myself and got a liitle help with Syntax and understanding. Here is the link for my stach overflow Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638095/knockout-table-paging